# replace custom tag with content from a file using custom Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm looking into creating a *custom tag helper* that replaces the original tag with content from an *external file*, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it when using *ProcessAsync*.

**The html**:

```
<body>
    <lc:default name="CSS" />
</body>
```

**DefaultResourceTagHelper.cs**:

```
namespace LC.Tools.Utility.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("lc:default", Attributes = "name", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
    public class DefaultResourceTagHelper : TagHelperBase
    {
        public DefaultResourceTagHelper(IHostingEnvironment env) : base(env) { }

        public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(GetUrl());
                var hwr = await wr.GetResponseAsync();

                if (hwr.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    using(Stream s = hwr.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                        {
                            string temp = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

                            context.Items.Clear();
                            context.Items.Add("test", temp);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }

        private string GetUrl() {
            string result = "http://lctools.lundbeckconsulting.no/Resource/" + this.Version + "/Default";

            switch(this.Name)
            {
                case ResourceNames.CSS:
                    result += "CSS.txt";
                    break;

                case ResourceNames.Script:
                    result += "SCRIPT.txt";
                    break;
            }

            return result;
        }

        [HtmlAttributeName("name")]
        public ResourceNames Name { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("version")]
        public string Version { get; set; } = "Latest";
    }

    public enum ResourceNames
    {
        Script,
        CSS
    }
}
```

**The file content of the external file**:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/IMAGES/fav-icon.png" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I'm looking to replace the `<lc:default name="CSS" />` tag with the file content, with the end result like this:

```
<body>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/IMAGES/fav-icon.png" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</body>
```

Comment: how does the file look ? can u provide an example of given value and expected result ?

Comment: the code at the bottom is what I'm expecting, and there you can also see the file content

Comment: can u point out the `fie-content` ?

Comment: I've now updated the question including the file content

Comment: will it always be `<lc:default name="CSS" />` ??

Comment: the name property accepts any name withing the ResourceNames enum, located at the bottom of the tag helper

Comment: `<lc:default name="anythingHere" />` , is this correct ?

Comment: yes looks corrent

Comment: i will provide an answer , it is of basic knowledge, hope it works :)

Comment: please do, anything will help :)

Comment: one last qs, HTML always contains 3 lines ?

Comment: no the file content will vary, so just replace the tag with the content

Comment: ok wait ... let me think a a bit :)

Comment: What exactly does not work or where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck at replacing the original tag with the content from my static file. I know how to change the name of tag and add attributes and all that, but not replacing it all together. I solved it with using a utility class to fetch the file and writes it with @Html.Raw, but it would be better to use a tag helper

Answer (score 0):

Assuming u read the HTML file from disk(if not then just add the html lines to the list `html`) , then follow this :

```
 private void test()
{
list<string> html = new list<string>(File.ReadAllLines("htmlFIlePathHere"));
list<string> myFile = new list<string>(File.ReadAllLines("filepathhere"));
int index;
string foundWord = "";
foreach (var ite in htmk)
{
    if (ite.Contains("<lc:default"))
    {
        index = html.FindIndex(a => a == ite);
        foundWord = ite;
    }
}

html(index).Replace(foundWord, "");
foreach (var item in myFile)
{
    html(index) = item;
    index = index + 1;
}
html.Add("<body>")
html.Add("</body>")

foreach (var item in html)
{
    MsgBox(item); /// u have a list of strings or should i say u have your  result, use it the way you want :)
}
}
```

Comment: you suggest reading the html and replacing the tag there? will this work with asp.net core when processing views and pages?

Comment: this has to work..however , i will add a few more lines :)

Comment: can u try it ??

Comment: I'm sorry its just very far from what I'm looking for. I need to do this from inside a tag helper and your method looks like is processing the html itself on load

Comment: re check my code....is you can read the html in ur taghelper , then loop through each line and add using `html.Add(line)`

Comment: i just debugged it , it works exactly as u expected :)

Comment: and don't forget to mark it as answer if it helped :)

Comment: give me a moment, one little thing to fix :)

Comment: I'm running into a problem since I don't know the name of the cshtml file. is it possible to access the html from the tag helper or do I need to inject HttpContext?

Comment: can u read the html from taghelper ? if so , how do u display the reuslt ?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! I ended up moving the GetResource method to an injected type and writes the content using @Html.Raw(). Not exactly what I was looking for but it works

Comment: did u implement this method ?